# Equivalent of Eclipse 'Show in' project explorer for Android studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, ide, intellij-13

In Eclipse is was always easy to search for a file int he project explorer.  Right click in the java file and do 'show in'.

[image]

this would reveal the file in the explorer for me instead of me hunting for it.  Where is the android studio's way of doing the same thing ? I've tried typing the name of the file in the project explorer but it doesn't seem to work.